# is it possible to switch from Relative layout to Linear layout without displacing the objects?

Tags: android, android-layout

I started my application with relative layout. I completed the entire registration form. i wanted to change the radio buttons to spinner. While replacing the radio buttons with spinner my entire form objects gets displaced. Is there a way to change relative layout to linear layout without affecting the objects?

Comment: Add the xml code

Answer (score 0):

You can add the XML Relativelayout and the result you expect. Sorry i cant comment